# How to deploy Istio on AKS Cluster through Azure DevOps pipeline?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, istio, azure-aks, azure-devops-pipelines

I need to deploy Istio (version- 1.7.3) on AKS cluster through Azure DevOps YAML pipeline ? How can I do that ? I am getting error currently. Code used by me is given below.

```
$artifactsLocation = "$PSScriptRoot/artifacts"
$ProgressPreference = 'SilentlyContinue'; Invoke-WebRequest -URI "https://github.com/istio/istio/releases/download/$IstioVersion/istio-$IstioVersion-win.zip" -OutFile "$artifactsLocation/istio-$IstioVersion.zip"
Expand-Archive -Path "$artifactsLocation/istio-$IstioVersion.zip" -DestinationPath $artifactsLocation
kubectl create namespace istio-system --save-config
$istioctl = "$PSScriptRoot/artifacts/istio-$IstioVersion/bin/istioctl.exe
Invoke-Expression "$istioctl install -f $kubernetesInfrastructurePath/aks/yaml/istio.servicemesh.yaml"
```

My pipeline task does not give me any error (I am calling powershell file with script which is added in pipeline as Azure CLI task) but I guess, the error might at the last line of code above. I am missing anything else to add here as I am totally clueless about the error.

On using "kubectl get all -n istio-operator" the output I get is "No resources found in istio-operator namespace."

**Update:-**

```
$istioctl = "$PSScriptRoot/artifacts/istio-$IstioVersion/bin/istioctl
```

When above line is used, the error is-

> The term '/home/vsts/work/1/s/pipelines/scripts/aks/artifacts/istio-1.7.3/bin/istioctl' is not recognized as a name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or executable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again

```
$istioctl = "$PSScriptRoot/artifacts/istio-$IstioVersion/bin/istioctl.exe
```

But when above line is used (**.exe added**), the error is-

> Error: no "view" mailcap rules found for type "application/x-msdos-program. /usr/bin/xdg-open: 869: www-browser: not found. /usr/bin/xdg-open: 869: links2: not found.  /usr/bin/xdg-open: 869: elinks: not found.  /usr/bin/xdg-open: 869: links: not found.   /usr/bin/xdg-open: 869: lynx: not found
> .   /usr/bin/xdg-open: 869: w3m: not found
> .   xdg-open: no method available for opening '/home/vsts/work/1/s/pipelines/scripts/aks/artifacts/istio-1.7.3/bin/istioctl.exe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue seems resolved now. No problem in code. The issue was with pool vmimage in pipeline. By mistake,  I was using ububtu image instead of windows.

Incorrect:-
vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'

Correct:-
vmImage: 'windows-latest'